# Create an instance of a List where the type derives from a base class and an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, generic-list

I have a class that will be storing objects that derive from a base class and implement an interface.  In this example, all the types derive from `UIElement` and implement my interface `IDropTarget`.

So in my class I have I can use generic type inference in a fantastic way to require this without restricting everything to a specific base class

```
public void AddDropTarget<TTarget>(TTarget target)
    where TTarget : UIElement, IDropTarget
{
    target.DoSomethingAsUIElement();
    target.DoSomethingAsIDropTraget();

    // Now I want to save it for another method
    list.Add(target);
}

public void DoStuff()
{
    foreach(var item in list)
    {
        item.MoreUIElementAndDropStuff();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way for me to store this TTarget restricted list.  I can't restrict it to a specific type because I have multiple classes that derive from UIElement already (Rectangle, Button, Grid, etc.), and there's no way for me to make all these object derive from a base type.

My next solution is going to be storing a list of each type.  I need to figure out if that overhead is worth it vs casting the objects each time I use them.

Comment: Why don't you make `list = new List<UIElement>();` ?

Comment: In your case, you could add `UIElement AsUIElement { get; }` to your interface. Then you can have a list of `IDropTarget` and do  something like `foreach(var item in list) { item.AsUIElement.Focus(); }`

Comment: Tony: I can't use List<UIElement> because I also need access to IDropTarget.

Comment: Kramer: That's an interesting solution that's a little similar to the Paolo's solution below.  I changed the answer to mark that one as the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want cast you can create the common base class you need with a variant of the decorator pattern.

```
//our new base type
public interface IElementAndDropTarget : IDropTarget
{
    void DoSomethingAsUIElement();
    void MoreUIElementAndDropStuff();
}

// our decorator. We need to store UIElement and IDropTarget
// as different fields. The static "Make" is giving you
// the compile-time guarantee that they both refer
// to the same class
public class UIElementDecorator : IElementAndDropTarget
{
    private readonly UIElement t;
    private readonly IDropTarget dt;

    private UIElementDecorator(UIElement t, IDropTarget dt)
    {   
        this.t=t;
        this.dt=dt;
    }

    public static UIElementDecorator Make<T>(T t) where T: UIElement, IDropTarget
    {
        return new UIElementDecorator(t,t);
    }

    public void DoSomethingAsUIElement() {t.DoSomethingAsUIElement();}
    public void MoreUIElementAndDropStuff(){t.MoreUIElementAndDropStuff();}
    public void DoSomethingAsIDropTarget() {dt.DoSomethingAsIDropTarget();}
}
```

with this, your list can be

```
public List<IElementAndDropTarget> list = new List<IElementAndDropTarget>();
```

in `AddDropTarget` you can populate it with the decorated classes as:

```
list.Add(UIElementDecorator.Make(target));
```

and that's it. The rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: I know it works, I just don't know why you would go through this pain, especially if you need more surface area from the UIElement/DropTarget than a single method or two.  It gets unwieldy fast. Just expose the base `UIElement` and `DropTarget` properties, and get rid of the methods on the both the interface and the decorator.  Then you can get rid of the interface too... now we don't need it.  So all you have is a simple class with containing object in two pre-cast public properties, and a static factory method on it to make new instances.

Comment: @AndrewBacker fair enough. If there are 10 or more methods to delegate, then the additional encapsulation may not be worth all the manual method-by-method delegations.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add two different types into a list this way.  You are basically saying that you want they generic type to be *either* `X` OR `Y`.  Imagine what would happen when you did a `foreach`, the compiler would not know if you wanted a `UIElement` or a `IDragDrop`.

You just have to maintain type safety manually.  Use a private list (like you are doing, I assume) and then do the cast manually.  It is up to you which type you want to use, or any.

```
public class MyClass {

    private _list = new List<object>();  // don't store any type info for now

    public void AddDropTarget.... /* this is already correct */

    public void RunUiStuff() {
        // get all items that are of type UIElement.  Items of wrong type will be ignored
        foreach(var e in _list.OfType<UIElement>()) {

        }
    }

    public void RunDropStuff() {
        // cast works as well, but will throw if any object is not the correct type
        foreach(var e in _list.Cast<IDropTarget>()) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The generics inference works on the method so at compile time it can verify that the parameter both derives from UIElement, and implement IDropTarget.  To be clear, I don't want a type that can be either X or Y, I want both, just like the TTarget definition is restricted to.  The compiler knows that the parameter must be both, and as such I can use methods from both types on the same variable.  

I figured that there was no way to get the same thing a List but it was worth asking.  And since the generics is enforcing the type safety, I don't have to worry about `.Cast<>` throwing anyway.

Comment: Of course :) They are two different types, can't combine them without a new base class.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question.  In my example above `AddDropTraget<TTarget>`, TTarget is in fact both types.  It is BOTH a UIElement AND an IDropTarget.  The generic type restrictions ensure that.  TTarget refers to any type that inherits from UIElement and implements IDropTarget.  So I could create a class called `MyDropButton : Button, IDropTarget` and another class called `MyDropTextBlock : TextBlock, IDropTarget`.  Both of these classes meet the restrain for TTarget, but there is no way for me to create a List<TTarget> that can contain both of these like AddDropTarget does.

Comment: Exactly.  Sorry if I'm not communicating clearly.  You would need a common base class for all your controls (like `MyButtonBase: UIElement, IDropTarget`).  You can constrain to multiple types, but classes like List are not constrained.  If you write a custom list class you can make the constraint.

Comment: Correct, if I had a common base class then I would be able to do something like that.  But I'm using the classes in WPF, so I can't make a common base class that would allow me to solve the problem.